# Interchanging Series and limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, inner-products

I have given a complex vector space $V$ together with a complex inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$.

Furthermore I have a sequence $(v_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in V^{\mathbb{N}}$ which has the property that $\langle v_{n},w\rangle\to\langle v,w\rangle$ for all $w\in V$, where $v\in V$ and I also have a sequence $(c_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}}$ which converges to $0$.

I have to show that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\vert c_{k}\vert^{2}\vert\langle x_{k},v_{n}-v\rangle\vert^{2}=0,$$

where $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of orthogonal elements in $V$, i.e. $\langle x_{n},x_{m}\rangle = \delta_{nm}$.

My Ansatz: If we are able to change the limit and the series, we are obviously done, since the condition $\langle v_{n},w\rangle\to\langle v,w\rangle$ for every $w$ exactly means that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\vert\langle x_{k},v_{n}-v\rangle\vert=0$.So my idea was to use dominated convergence, which means that we have to find some sequence $g_{n}$ such that

$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:\vert c_{k}\vert^{2}\vert\langle x_{k},v_{n}-v\rangle\vert^{2}\leq g_{k}$$
and
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}g_{k}<\infty.$$

(I hope this is right so far.)

For this reason I started to write

$$\vert c_{k}\vert^{2}\vert\langle x_{k},v_{n}-v\rangle\vert^{2}\leq \vert c_{k}\vert^{2}\Vert x_{k}\Vert^{2}(\Vert v_{n}\Vert^{2} - \Vert v\Vert^{2})=\vert c_{k}\vert^{2}(\Vert v_{n}\Vert^{2} - \Vert v\Vert^{2})$$

using Cauchy-Schwartz, the orthogonality of the $x_{n}$ as well as the triangle inequality. My next step would be that I know that every sequence with the property $\langle v_{n},w\rangle\to\langle v,w\rangle$ is bounded (a fact I know from the lecture) and hence:

$$\vert c_{k}\vert^{2}\vert\langle x_{k},v_{n}-v\rangle\vert^{2}\leq \vert c_{k}\vert^{2}(\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\Vert v_{n}\Vert^{2} - \Vert v\Vert^{2})=\mathrm{const.}\vert c_{k}\vert^{2}$$

But the problem now is that I think that I have done something wrong, because I am not sure if one can say that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\vert c_{k}\vert^{2}<\infty$$

only by knowing that $c_{k}\to 0$.

Any ideas?

Comment: The inequality $\lvert\langle x_k, v_n - v\rangle\rvert^2 \leqslant \lVert v_n\rVert^2 - \lvert v\rVert^2$ doesn't generally hold. The best you can generally prove is $\lvert\langle x_k, v_n - v\rangle\rvert^2 \leqslant (\lVert v_n\rVert + \lVert v\rVert)^2$. That doesn't change anything fundamental, you just get a different constant factor. **If** $\sum \lvert c_k\rvert^2 < +\infty$ you can use dominated convergence as you planned. But consider e.g. $c_k = \frac{1}{\log (k+2)}$ to see that $c_k \to 0$ is very far from implying $\sum \lvert c_k\rvert^2 < +\infty$.

Comment: The typical way to go about it is to split the sum. On the tail, $\lvert c_k\rvert$ is small, and since $$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \lvert\langle x_k, v_n-v\rangle\rvert^2 \leqslant \lVert v_n - v\rVert^2$$ is bounded uniformly in $n$, you can make the tail as small as you please by splitting at a large enough $k$. The finite initial part of the sum you can make small by choosing $n$ large enough.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But weak convergence does in general NOT apply strong convergence....in other words, $\langle v_{n},w\rangle\to\langle v,w\rangle$ does not imply that $\Vert v_{n}-v\Vert\to 0$....

Comment: Right. But as you noted, weak convergence implies boundedness. Hmm, however, unless we require $V$ be complete, we are given less than weak convergence, and thus $v_n$ might be unbounded, in which case the assertion need not hold. But if $v_n$ is bounded, the argument I outlined works. What is needed (besides $\langle v_n - v, w\rangle \to 0$ for all $w$) is a $C$ such that $\sum_k \lvert\langle x_k, v_n - v\rangle\rvert^2 \leqslant C$ for all $n$.

Comment: Ahh yes I unterstand.... Yes indeed according to the exercise V is complete, I just forgot to write it.... Thanks a lot!